# Logic for prioritising elements in the dom using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GMH6q/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="feature" id="about">about</div>
<div class="feature" id="services">services</div>
<div class="feature" id="products">products</div>

<label>About</label><input type="checkbox" data-id="about" />
<label>Services</label><input type="checkbox" data-id="services" />
<label>Products</label><input type="checkbox" data-id="products" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var priority = {'about':1, 'services':2, 'products':3};
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var el = $(this).attr('data-id');        
        if($(this).is(':checked')){                        
           $('.feature').hide();             
           $('.feature#' + el).show();
        } else {
           $('.feature#' + el).hide();    
        }
    });              
});
```

If `about` is on, then clicking any other checkbox won't have any effect.
Likewise if `services` is on, putting `products` on won't have any effect, but putting `about` in, will just show `about`.
If all are on, then `about` just shows.
If all are off, nothing shows.

The priority array needs to be integrated in somehow, but I dont know how. If someone could help me with some logic and integrating the array, that would be great!

Comment: Please always include the relevant information (this includes code) directly in your question.

Comment: what about using radio buttons?

Comment: @chepe263 How would this help please?

Comment: what i understand is you want just one checkbox on and the rest off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NAdCP/20/

Requires data-id to be the same as the keys in your priority object, and it's not very elegant but it does what you wanted, and I took it a step further to make sure that it falls back to the next highest checked priority item when you uncheck an item (if there is one)

edited to also indicate that there is an extra key in your priority object called 'highest' to determine the initial edge point, and could be called anything, or replaced with a better mechanism

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var priority = {'about':1, 'services':2, 'products':3, 'highest':4};
    var highest = priority['highest']
    var current = highest;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var el = $(this).attr('data-id');
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            if(priority[el] < current ){
               current = priority[el];          
               $('.feature').hide();             
               $('.feature#' + el).show();
            }
        } else {
            if(priority[el] == current){
               $('.feature#' + el).hide();
               var pNext= highest;
                var pNextName= "";
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked')){
                        var elNext = $(this).attr('data-id');
                        if(priority[elNext] < pNext){
                            pNext = priority[elNext];
                            pNextName= elNext;
                        }
                    }
                });

                current = pNext;
                if(current != highest && pNextName != ""){
                    $('.feature#' + pNextName).show();
                }
            }
        }        
    });              
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. It also disables the checkboxes that are not permitted. Is this what you're after?
**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GMH6q/4/

```
var features = ['about', 'services', 'products'],
    $inputs = $('input:checkbox'),
    $divs = $('.feature');

$inputs.change(function() {

    $inputs.prop('disabled', false);

    var name = $(this).attr('data-id'),
        idx = features.indexOf(name),
        arr = features.slice(idx + 1, features.lenght);

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
            $('input:checkbox[data-id="' + v + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
        });
        $divs.hide().eq(idx).show();
    } else {
        $divs.hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: This is actually awesome! However, the disabling part is a little redundant as i need to still know they've checked one on (for a form), but only show the html of the highest priority checked on one!